# opencv window in tkinter frame

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am making a hand controlled media player application in Python and through OpenCV.I want to embed gesture window of OpenCV in Tkinter frame so I can add further attributes to it.
Can someone tell how to embed OpenCV camera window into Tkinter frame?

Comment: camera window in Tkinter window is not good idea. Both windows use own mainloop (event loop) which can't work at the same time (or you have to use `threading`) and don't have contact one with other. Maybe easier is get camera video frame and display in Tkinter window (on Label or Canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV window in Tkinter window is not good idea. Both windows use own mainloop (event loop) which can't work at the same time (or you have to use threading) and don't have contact one with other.

Probably it is easier to get video frame and display in Tkinter window on Label or Canvas. You can use `tk.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to run periodically function which will update video frame in Tkinter window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Now that you know what i want to make ,can you suggest something for my GUI problem. I want all attributes to run simultaneoulsy, not periodically.

Comment: You can use `after()` to run two functions periodically and it will look like they work simultaneoulsy. Other way you have to use threads. (BTW: threads work very similar - system run two threads periodically and it looks like they work simultaneoulsy. Only system can stop one thread at every moment and run another)